How to stretch vertically the content of frame so that it fills up the frame?
I have a frame in beamer:
\documentclass{beamer}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\itemsymbol{$\blacktriangleright$}
\let\svpar\par
\let\svitemize\itemize
\let\svenditemize\enditemize
\let\svitem\item
\let\svcenter\center
\let\svendcenter\endcenter
\let\svcolumn\column
\let\svendcolumn\endcolumn
\def\newitem{\renewcommand\item[1][\itemsymbol]{\vfill\svitem[##1]}}%
\def\newpar{\def\par{\svpar\vfill}}%
\newcommand\stretchon{%
  \newpar%
  \renewcommand\item[1][\itemsymbol]{\svitem[##1]\newitem}%
  \renewenvironment{itemize}%
    {\svitemize}{\svenditemize\newpar\par}%
  \renewenvironment{center}%
    {\svcenter\newpar}{\svendcenter\newpar}%
  \renewenvironment{column}[2]%
    {\svcolumn{##1}\setlength{\parskip}{\columnskip}##2}%
    {\svendcolumn\vspace{\columnskip}}%
}
\newcommand\stretchoff{%
  \let\par\svpar%
  \let\item\svitem%
  \let\itemize\svitemize%
  \let\enditemize\svenditemize%
  \let\center\svcenter%
  \let\endcenter\svendcenter%
  \let\column\svcolumn%
  \let\endcolumn\svendcolumn%
}
\newlength\columnskip
\columnskip 0pt
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\stretchon

\begin{frame}
We have A.

We have B.
\begin{enumerate}
\item We have C.
\item We have D.
\end{enumerate}
\begin{lemma}
Let E hold.
\begin{itemize}
\item Then F holds.
\item Then G holds.
\end{itemize}
\end{lemma}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Its content is

I would like to stretch vertically the content of frame so that it fills up the frame. I tried \stretchon from this answer:

As you can see, there are two problems:

The numbering in \begin{enumerate}...\end{enumerate} is undesirably replaced by \blacktriangleright.

There is no effect inside \begin{lemma}...\end{lemma}.


Could you explain how to get my desired stretching?

In your real presentation, will the block have a background colour?

The solution to How do I ask LaTeX to exactly fill up a page? achieves the same as \stretchon above, but without the triangles. But the lemma does not spread either.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yess, the block have background color.

@Akira In this case, I would suggest to add fixed-height spaces within the block and not trying to make it fill



The numbering in \begin{enumerate}...\end{enumerate} is undesirably replaced by \blacktriangleright.


Instead of overwriting the definition of lists, you could use the trick from https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=832#a2071
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{parskip}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{s}[true]{% stretch
  \beamer@frametopskip=0pt\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[s]
We have A.

We have B.
\begin{enumerate}
\item We have C.
\item We have D.
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



You solution is almost there. Is it possible to modify it to affect also the environment \begin{lemma}...\end{lemma} or more generally \begin{block}...\end{block}?

@Akira As I already said in comments, if you need your blocks to have a background colour, then I would add fixed space there and not try to make the stretchy.

Could you explain why we should not stretch the blocks?

@Akira Blocks are essentially minipages without a fixed height. Their height will match their content - so any stretch will be zero. Try \documentclass{article} \begin{document} \begin{minipage}{\linewidth} test \vfill test \end{minipage} \end{document} with and without the minipage around the content.

@Akira If you wouldn't need a background colour, my suggestion would have been to define the lemma without a block around it.
